# How to use cache for image in rails 4

Tags: image, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing `rails 4 application`.

Where on 1 page, `large size image loaded 5 times`. So i need to load that image once and rest places display `using cache` or something but do not want to loaded it again.

Any way to `cache` or other to display image in `rails 4`

Thanks